# npm ERR! could not determine executable to run - Every time I load up VS Code and try to open Cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, cypress

Basically as per title, every time I load up Visual Studio Code and go to run 'npx open cypress' I get the below message in my terminal.

**npm ERR! could not determine executable to run**

If I do 'npx cypress -v' it gives me version details, So im a bit stumped.

Tried deleting the node_modules folder and re-running 'npm install' and 'npm install cypress --save-dev'

Currently having to use .exe download of cypress because of this issue.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to install Cypress globally? `npm install -g cypress`

Comment: @IncrediblePony just tried it, still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try with yarn: yarn add cypress maybe it's more stable than npm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reverse the command

```js
npx cypress open
```

Comment: That did it, Thanks.